# Ajax toolscript Manager in master page

Tags: asp.net, ajax, visual-studio

I know that we can only add 1 `toolscript manager`. But what happen when we have master page.

Is it possible to define `toolscript manager` in both master page and content Page.
If no than what is best way to define `toolscript manager`.
In master page or in content page.
And both master page and content page have ajax function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to keep `ToolkitScriptManager` control inside MasterPage. This ensures that al content pages that are based on a master page can use `ToolkitScriptManager`'s functionality out of the box.

When you need programmatic access to `ToolkitScriptManager` control you can use FindControl method, like this (where "tkScriptManager" is id of your ToolkitScriptManagerControl):

```
var toolkitScriptManager = Page.Master.FindControl("tkScriptManager") as ToolkitScriptManager;
```

Hope this helps!

Regards,
Uros